# How can I play the first url that I get when I search in youtube with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, youtube

I trying to do a program in vb.net that will search a video on youtube by words and play the first url (the first result) that I will get without waiting to client to choose.

Someone can help me?

I did the search but I dont know how to do that it will play the first video that I will get automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. What form you choose to develop this program ? Webform ? Winform?
2. I assume that the form is winform, then you could use the "WebBrowser" (you can find the "WebBrowser" in the toolbox)

   ```
   Private Sub openYouTube()

       WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/?gl=TW")

   End Sub
   ```
3. Find the search bar on the youtube (use GetElementByID) and insert the string which you want to search (Use SetAttribute). The ID of the inputbox of youtube search bar is "search" (How to find the ID of any element in a webpage? Target the element and click the right button of mouse, choose "inspect" for Chrome, "inspect element" for IE, it would show the element detail)
   [image]

   ```
   Private Sub inputString&SearchIt()

       Dim theStringYouWantToSearch as string

       WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("search").SetAttribute("value", theStringYouWantToSearch)

   End Sub
   ```
4. Execute the search (Use InvokeMember("click") to fire the search)

   ```
   Private Sub executeSearch()

       WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("search-icon-legacy").InvokeMember("click")

   End Sub
   ```
5. Find the first result and record the URL.
   This process is more complicated, use GetElementsByTagName to get a collection of result tables, the first result is the first item of this collection. Find the table of first result then loop through all elements of this table, to find the element which id is "thumbnail", and this element has the information of part of URL.

   ```
   Private Sub findFirstResult()

      Dim elemCollection as HtmlElementCollection
      Dim firstResultTable as HtmlElement
      Dim hrefString as string
      Dim resultURL as string

      elemcollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("ytd-video-renderer")

      firstResultTable = elemCollection.item(0)

      For each element as HtmlElement in firstResultTable.All
          If element.Id = "thumbnail" then
             hrefString = element.GetAttribute("href")
          End if
      Next

      resultURL = "https://www.youtube.com" & hrefString

   End Sub
   ```
6. Between every step, you have to wait for the complement of webpage loading, or the program wouldn't find the element. There are several ways to do that, you could do some search for that.